# GitLab CI/CD yml - How to add into pipeline job if new branch created. And exclude for further pushes?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

In our git process we have hothix process. The process is to create a hotfix brunch from master and make changes and then merge to master back.

The issue that I'm faсing now is how to add job to pipelne if branch just created and exclude from pipeline for any further push?

When branch is created we need to set up custom environment. Create a sandbox, push code and push some test data. This is need only when branch is created. In case of changes and pushes, environment is available and no need in building it again. Just build code and push a release tag

I'm trying something like this:

```
job-name:
  stage: build
  script:
    - myScript
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^hotfix.*/'
      changes:
        - force-app/**/*
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^hotfix.*/'
      allow_failure: false
      when: manual
```

And for sure it's not working as `changes:` not part of `if` policy:

```
Rules are evaluated in order until a match is found. If a match is found, the attributes are checked to see if the job should be added to the pipeline.
```

Comment: It's hard to do such logic by checking whether the pushed commit is the first commit of a new branch because it is possible that the branch is created in local machine and only pushed after a few commits in which case the pushed commit is 3rd or 10th commit of the branch. What's more reliable is to have the environment creation job to check using suitable command if the environment has been created or not, rather than relying on checking the git tree.

Comment: @Lukman, thanks. Any suggestions how to check if environment is exist?

Comment: Depends on what kind of environment you are creating. Is it new EKS, ECS, EC2, GCP, AKS, etc?

Comment: @Lukman, I'm not so experienced. I was talking about GitLab environment. But looks like you are saying that I can't avoid running job to understand if my non GitLab evironment is running. Can I some how understand that GitLab environment is on, without scrip run to exclude this job?